# copy a table to another table with this conditions

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

copy a table another table with this conditions

1. if a record in old table is new copy It to new table
2. if a record in old table has changed and that record existing in new
   table update that record info in new table

Comment: Talk about sparse on details....this maybe sounds like you are trying to create a trigger? Without any more details than posted this is likely to get closed. You might want to view this page. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making some big assumptions about what you are trying to do, but.... if I guessed right, this should get you close :

```
Insert Into New_Table
Select  *
From    Old_Table
Where   NOT EXISTS ( Select * from New_Table )

Update New_Table NT
From     Old_Table OT
Where   NT.PK = OT.PK
   and    ( NT.attrib_fld_1   <>   OT.atrib_fld_1
    OR
     NT.attrib_fld_1   <>   OT.atrib_fld_1
    OR
     NT.attrib_fld_1   <>   OT.atrib_fld_1
    OR
     NT.attrib_fld_1   <>   OT.atrib_fld_1
    -- etc..for as many non key fields as need evaluated 
    )
```

Comment: I think I can get it using just your sample SQL :
 
 
 
UPDATE
    Test02.dbo.Test 
SET
    Test02.dbo.Test.fld1 =  Test01.dbo.Test.fld1,
    Test02.dbo.Test.fld2 =  Test01.dbo.Test.fld2
FROM
    Test01.dbo.Test
INNER JOIN
    Test02.dbo.Test
ON 
    Test02.dbo.Test.PK = Test01.dbo.Test.PK

Comment: USE [Test01]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Test]    Script Date: 08/08/2015 03:02:27 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
 [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
 [FName] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: the error message after exec the Update statment
" Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'From'

Comment: Question....Test01 and Test02 are database owners, yes ?   Or are these DB instances and dbo is the owner ?

Comment: Test01 And Test 02 Are database And dbo.Test Is table

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/wfQhHfk.png

Comment: Ah...  that helps.     The SET phrase is needed.  look at my post from ~ 35 minutes back... you need the SET TEST02 .....   =     TEST01....    to direct the engine on field movements...

Comment: UPDATE
    TEST02.dbo.Test 

SET
    Test02.dbo.Test.fName =  Test01.dbo.Test.fName
          
FROM
    Test01.dbo.Test
    
INNER JOIN
    Test02.dbo.Test
   
ON 
    Test02.dbo.Test.ID = Test01.dbo.Test.ID

Comment: Thank you My problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

```html
--Here is an example with merge statement

USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.NewTable(EmployeeID int, EmployeeName varchar(10), 
     CONSTRAINT NewTable_PK PRIMARY KEY(EmployeeID));
CREATE TABLE dbo.OldTable(EmployeeID int, EmployeeName varchar(10), 
     CONSTRAINT OldTable_PK PRIMARY KEY(EmployeeID));
GO
INSERT dbo.NewTable(EmployeeID, EmployeeName) VALUES(100, 'Mary');
INSERT dbo.NewTable(EmployeeID, EmployeeName) VALUES(101, 'Sara');
INSERT dbo.NewTable(EmployeeID, EmployeeName) VALUES(102, 'Stefano');
INSERT dbo.NewTable(EmployeeID, EmployeeName) Values(103, 'John');

GO
INSERT dbo.OldTable(EmployeeID, EmployeeName) Values(103, 'Bob');
INSERT dbo.OldTable(EmployeeID, EmployeeName) Values(104, 'Steve');

GO

USE tempdb;
GO
BEGIN TRAN;
MERGE [NewTable] AS T
USING [OldTable] AS S
ON (T.EmployeeID = S.EmployeeID) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    THEN INSERT(EmployeeID, EmployeeName) VALUES(S.EmployeeID, S.EmployeeName)
WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN UPDATE SET T.EmployeeName = S.EmployeeName

OUTPUT $action, inserted.*, deleted.*;

IF @@ERROR <> 0
 ROLLBACK TRAN; 
ELSE
 COMMIT TRAN;
GO
```